# WooCommerce Rest API internal_server_error when creating a product

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have been using the Rest API to create products without any issues. Until a few days ago, it is now returning a internal_server_error error, with a message, There has been a critical error on this website. Status 500.

I have not installed any new plugins since it stopped working, there is a chance plugins have been updated.

When looking a little deeper, I can see that the rest api is creating an entry into wp_posts table, but nothing in the wp_postmeta table.

I have enabled WP_DEBUG but there are no error logs showing. I have also disabled plugins and still it wont work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this. A WooCommerce update was installed last night 7.8.1
This was causing the fatal error:

> CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function `wc_get_default_product_type_options()`

Once I rolled back to version 7.8.0 it worked.